# ModelChoiceField options not taken into account in the HTML rendering

Tags: django, django-forms

I am currently working on an application and I have a problem with my ModelForm.

I feel like the options that I put in my ModelChoiceField is not being taken into account.

This is my forms.py:

```
class PlayerModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return '{} from {} at {} '.format(obj.name, obj.team, obj.price)


class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, contest_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        contest = ContestLOL.objects.filter(id=contest_id)[0]
        teams = contest.teams.all()
        players = Player.objects.filter(team__in=teams).order_by('-price')
        
        self.fields['top'].queryset = players.filter(role='Top')
        self.fields['jungle'].queryset = players.filter(role='Jungle')
        self.fields['mid'].queryset = players.filter(role='Mid')
        self.fields['adc'].queryset = players.filter(role='ADC')
        self.fields['support'].queryset = players.filter(role='Support')

        self.fields['top'].initial = players.filter(role='Top')[0]
        self.fields['jungle'].initial = players.filter(role='Jungle')[0]
        self.fields['mid'].initial = players.filter(role='Mid')[0]
        self.fields['adc'].initial = players.filter(role='ADC')[0]
        self.fields['support'].initial = players.filter(role='Support')[0]

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = {'top': PlayerModelChoiceField(
                                    queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Top'), 
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
                                    empty_label=None, 
                                    to_field_name="top"),
                  'jungle': PlayerModelChoiceField(
                                    queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Jungle'), 
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
                                    empty_label=None, 
                                    to_field_name="jungle"),
                  'mid': PlayerModelChoiceField(
                                    queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Mid'), 
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
                                    empty_label=None, 
                                    to_field_name="mid"),
                   'adc': PlayerModelChoiceField(
                                    queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='ADC'), 
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
                                    empty_label=None, 
                                    to_field_name="adc"),
                   'support': PlayerModelChoiceField(
                                    queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Support'), 
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
                                    empty_label=None, 
                                    to_field_name="supp")
        }
        fields = {'top', 'jungle', 'mid', 'adc', 'support'}
```

This is is my view.py:

```
def contest(request, slug=None):
    contest = get_object_or_404(ContestLOL, slug=slug)
    matches= Match.objects.filter(contest=contest.id)
    form = Form(contest.id, request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        bet = form.save(commit=False)
        bet.user = request.user
        bet.contest = contest
        bet.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Bet was saved')
        form = Form(contest.id)

    output = { "contest": contest,
                "form": form,
                "matches": matches
                }
    return render(request, "questions/contest.html", output)
```

And this is contest.html:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    Top : 
    <br>
    {{form.top}}
    <hr>

    Jungle : 
    <br>
    {{form.jungle}}
    <hr>

    Mid : 
    <br>
    {{form.mid}}
    <hr>
  
    ADC : 
    <br>
    {{form.adc}}

    <hr>
  
  
    Support : 
    <br>
    {{form.support}}
    <hr>
    
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value='Submit'>
</form>
```

And a screenshot of what I get is:

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dOaC.png

As you can see, there is no RadioSelectWidget and there is still the empty label.
So that makes me think, that the options of the ModelChoiceField is not working.
Did anyone had the same case before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you define `fields` twice in your `Meta`, hence only the *last* one will persist. But even if you would use the dictionary you use, that is *not* the way to define fields. You define the fields that the form class level, so:

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    top = PlayerModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Top'), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
        empty_label=None, 
        to_field_name='top'
    )
    jungle = PlayerModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Jungle'), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
        empty_label=None, 
        to_field_name='jungle'
    )
    mid = PlayerModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Mid'), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
        empty_label=None, 
        to_field_name='mid'
    )
    adc = PlayerModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='ADC'), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
        empty_label=None, 
        to_field_name='adc'
    )
    support = PlayerModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Player.objects.filter(role='Support'), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
        empty_label=None, 
        to_field_name='supp'
    )

    def __init__(self, contest_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['top'].initial = players.filter(role='Top')[0]
        self.fields['jungle'].initial = players.filter(role='Jungle')[0]
        self.fields['mid'].initial = players.filter(role='Mid')[0]
        self.fields['adc'].initial = players.filter(role='ADC')[0]
        self.fields['support'].initial = players.filter(role='Support')[0]

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('top', 'jungle', 'mid', 'adc', 'support')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I took what you did, which makes way more sens than the code that I wrote. But I get an error that feels strange: ```'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'``` When I search in all my files attname, nothing comes up. Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: @mbel: can you edit your question and share the full traceback?

Comment: I will probably ask a new question and close this one. I feel like this a total different matter. Thank you